# Toggling the html contained in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a div so that when clicked it will convert temperature to fahrenheit and when clicked again it will revert back to the celsius reading that is originally pulled in by the api.

The code works when I am only dealing with the numbers:

```
var fahrenheit = (data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(2);
var celsius = data.main.temp; 

$("#temp").on("click", function() {
$("#temp").html($("#temp").html() == fahrenheit ? celsius : fahrenheit)

});
```

But it does not work when I try to add text to the html, it toggles once to the fahrenheit conversion, but doesn't toggle back when clicked again.

```
var fahrenheit = (data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(2);
var celsius = data.main.temp;

$("#temp").on("click", function() {
$("#temp").html($("#temp").html() == fahrenheit + "&deg F" ? celsius + "&deg C" : fahrenheit + "&deg F")

});
```

I'm a bit stumped on this. I've had a search around but I can't seem to find a solution that fits what I want to do.

Thanks for any help.

Here is a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/seekingcat/pen/jLzVKb?editors=0010)

Comment: So `#temp` is a ... ?? Please include markup.

Comment: Sorry, new to using this site, #temp is an id of an element. I'll edit my original post to include a link to the codepen. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: My guess is that it could have something to do with the `&deg`. When put in html it turns to `°`, and how would that compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the check through JavaScript onclick.

When you check it, you are using JavaScript so instead of using the HTML entity of degrees, you should simply use the degrees char:

Change this:

```
$("#temp").html($("#temp").html() == fahrenheit + "&deg F" ? celsius + "&deg C" : fahrenheit + "&deg F")
```

to this:

```
$("#temp").html($("#temp").html() == fahrenheit + "° F" ? celsius + "&deg; C" : fahrenheit + "&deg; F" )
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The simplicity of my question obviously indicates my inexperience. That works perfectly.

Comment: No worry and happy coding with your weather app :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if it is showing in celsius currently and then make a decision based on that

```
$("#temp").on("click", function() {
  var isCelsius = $(this).html().indexOf('C') > -1;
  $('#temp').html(isCelsius ? celsius + '&deg C' : fahrenheit + '&deg F');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use html() to get the value you get parsed HTML so you have no `&deg` HTML entity but parsed value.

To fix your code you can compare the hexcode value of degree entity.

```
$("#temp").on("click", function() {
  $("#temp").html($("#temp").text() == fahrenheit + "\xB0 F" ? celsius + "\xB0 C" : fahrenheit + "\xB0 F")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare just the numbers (without the last 3 '° F or ° C' characters).

```js
var fahrenheit = (data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(2);
var celsius = data.main.temp;

$("#temp").on("click", function() {
  var numberOnly = $("#temp").html().length - 3;
  $("#temp").html($("#temp").html().substring(0, numberOnly) == fahrenheit ? celsius + "&deg C" : fahrenheit + "&deg F");
});
```